# CS.ini automatically select task sequence based on model

Tags: sccm, mdt, wds

What I want to accomplish is for MDT to automatically select the task sequence based on the model, and if there is no match to run a generic deployment. but it's not selecting the task sequence automatically. any idea, how can i achieve this goal. Thanks

```
[Settings]
Priority=Models,Default
Properties=MyCustomProperty, ShortModel

[Default]
_SMSTSOrgName=myCompany
SkipAppsOnUpgrade=NO
UserDatalocation=AUTO
OSDComputerName=#Left("%Model%",4)#
DoCapture=NO
OSInstall=YES
SkipAdminPassword=YES
SkipBDDWelcome=YES
SkipBitLocker=YES
SkipCapture=YES
SkipComputerName=YES
SkipFinalSummary=YES
SkipLocaleSelection=YES
SkipProductKey=YES
SkipSummary=YES
SkipTaskSequence=NO
SkipComputerBackup=YES
SkipTimeZone=YES
SkipUserData=YES
TimeZone=035
TimeZoneName=Eastern Standard Time


[Models]
ShortModel=#Left("%Model%",4)#
Subsection=TS-%ShortModel%

[TS-20L8]
TaskSequenceID=TS-20L8
SkipApplications=YES


SkipTaskSequence=Yes

[TS-20QG]
TaskSequenceID=TS-20QG
SkipApplications=NO
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after hours of search, I found that this method works perfectly for Dell and HP series whereas for Lenovo you have to make some changes in the ZtiGather script to get the proper model of the system.

reference link: [%make% and %model%][1]

```
[Settings]
Priority=make,Default

[Default]
_SMSTSOrgName=myCompany
SkipAppsOnUpgrade=NO
UserDatalocation=AUTO
DoCapture=NO
OSInstall=YES
SkipAdminPassword=YES
SkipBDDWelcome=YES
SkipBitLocker=YES
SkipCapture=YES
SkipComputerName=YES
SkipFinalSummary=YES
SkipLocaleSelection=YES
SkipProductKey=YES
SkipSummary=YES
SkipTaskSequence=NO
SkipComputerBackup=YES
SkipTimeZone=YES
SkipUserData=YES
TimeZone=035
TimeZoneName=Eastern Standard Time

[TS-20L8]
TaskSequenceID=TS-20L8
SkipApplications=YES

[TS-20QG]
TaskSequenceID=TS-20QG
SkipApplications=NO


  [1]: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/20b88227-2bd6-4279-8752-58773274c6ce/make-and-model?forum=mdt
```